# What causes aluminum to darken when touched?

Tags: thermodynamics, metals

The rear side of my graphics card (the side that has the HDMI port) seems to be made of aluminum.

I noticed that whenever I touch it with my clean finger, I leave a dark trail onto it that is around a shade or two darker. If you afterwards wipe it with a cloth it goes away, only to return immediately upon being touched by skin.

Would this be related to the oxide layers on the surface, given that the aluminum often gets hot when the GPU is under load?

[picture](https://ibb.co/6ySzN9m)

- those dark dot-like spots also appeared. I am assuming it’s aluminum spotting.

GPU model: 3060Ti LHR by MSI

Comment: I think this is a question more appropriate for the Chemistry  site.

Comment: A chemical reaction with oxidation processes